# REACT-TS import jsonFile from './file.json' returns undefined

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, import, react-tsx

I'm trying to use the data from a json file using `import file from ./file.json` but it does not return anything. I tried using `require('./file.json')` instead and it worked just fine on console, but it doesn't recognize the `require` module on the browser. I really want to find a way to use data inside the json file without recurring to `require` (I understand it comes from NodeJS).

This the code where I do the imports:

```js
// requestsRouting.ts
import tenEmailReports from './tenReports.json'
import twentyEmailReports from './twentyReports.json'

export const requestsRouting = {
    tenEmailReports,
    twentyEmailReports
}
```

As I said, the routes are fine because I can access them properly using `require`. I then import `requestsRouting` and do a simple `console.log(data)` and throws `undefined`.

```js
// index.ts
import { requestsRouting as routes } from './requestsRouting'

const data = routes.tenEmailReports
console.log(data)
```

Finally, here's `tenReports.json` file to show the format:

```json
// tenReports.json
[
 {
    "id": 1,
    "study_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2018-01-01"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "study_id": 2,
    "created_at": "2019-07-18"
  },
  ...
  {
    "id": 10,
    "study_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-09-23"
  }
]
```

I tried solving the problem in many ways, I even loaded the data on a typescript file and then exported it with `export default data` but it keeps throwing undefined ¿How can I solve this issue?